# What do you call "#" in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am just curious, what do you call `#` in C/C++?

For example, `#if`. Is it called "hashtag if"?

Comment: There is no special name for it in C or C++ specifically. According to internet this symbol is generally called "Octothorpe, number, pound, sharp, or hash"

Comment: "Pound" is the most common pronunciation I hear to verbalize "#" in a C context.
I.E. #define -> "Pound Define"

Comment: How exactly is this opinion-based? There are several formal and canonical names for it in the language grammar. The question _can_ be answered with facts and citations. Re-open vote.

Comment: "Pound" in the US, "hash" in a lot of other places (definitely in the UK), "hastag" never

Comment: I was writing an answer including the mysterious but unloved _non-directive_ (C17 6.10). It never gets any attention otherwise.

Comment: @AlanBirtles indeed. One would pronounce something of the form "#tag" as hashtag, because it is a hash followed by a tag.

Comment: I always thought these these things were called hash, slash, dash etc out of ancient programming tradition rather than some US vs UK English thing.

Comment: I always tried to _write_ C and/or C++ correctly. I appreciate that OP tries additionally to _speak_ it correctly.

Comment: I've always called `#` "pound sign", so `#if` would be "pound sign if" See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and suggestions and big thanks to mkrieger1 who edited my question into a better way to ask. Appreciate it.

Comment: Personally I call it "preprocessor-if"

Comment: "Hashtag" is a very new term, tracing back to about 2007.  Both C and C++ are far older than this (even C# is older).

Answer (score 6):

A line in the source code starting with something like `#if` is called a [preprocessor directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_(programming)#The_C_preprocessor) nowadays. In the book *The C Programming Language* ("K&R")<sup>1</sup>, it is called a "compiler-control line".

The symbol `#` itself does not seem to have a special name. For example, the [documentation for the gcc compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/The-preprocessing-language.html#The-preprocessing-language) just calls it '#':

> Preprocessing directives are lines in your program that start with
> ‘#’. Whitespace is allowed before and after the ‘#’. The ‘#’ is
> followed by an identifier, the directive name. It specifies the
> operation to perform. Directives are commonly referred to as ‘#name’
> where name is the directive name. For example, ‘#define’ is the
> directive that defines a macro.

The *K&R* book also just calls it '#':

> Lines beginning with # communicate with this preprocessor.

---

[<sup>1</sup>](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/page/n214/mode/1up) *Dennis Ritchie, Brian Kernighan; The C Programming Language, 1st edition (1978); p. 207*

Comment: There is also the # operator, which is the second use of the symbol in the language. Informally/slang for it is "stringification operator" or some such.

Answer (score 5):

The C standard does not refer to `#` by name. In C 2018 6.4.6, it is listed as one of the punctuator characters. It has three uses in C. In discussing its use in preprocessor directives, the standard calls it “the `#` processing token” (6.10). In discussing its use for the “stringizing” operation, the standard calls it “The # operator” (6.10.3.2). And of course it may be used as a character in character constants (`'#'`) or string literals.

Comment: And two `##` makes the `##` operator, "pp token concatenation".

Answer (score 1):

'#' is called pre-processor directive and the word after '#' is called pre-processor command. Pre-processor is a program which performs before compilation. Each pre-processing directive must be on its own line.
Example -

```
#define MAX 50
#if CONDITION
```

Answer (score 0):

The **#** symbol is called an **Octothorpe**

- so the `#if` conjunction is described as "octothorpe if"

Note:
The C language was invented at Bell Labs, and it was the guys at Bell Labs who designated this symbol as an Octothorpe. [Reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octothorpe)

Comment: Although the `#` symbol is called an Octothorpe, in all of my years as a C++ developer I have never once heard a single developer either seriously or ironically refer to it as "Octothorpe if". Not at a conference. Not at work. Not anywhere. This answer is a pure fabrication.

Comment: That is the etymology of the symbol. Also, I, for one, refer to it as an octothorpe every time I talk about it.